# Change automatic const placement in Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt-creator

Suppose I am creating the following function:

```
double f(double const& x) { return x + x; }
```

This is how I like to place the `const`  modifier, not like `const double`. However, Qt Creator automatically places it in the other position. For example, if I declared the above function in a header file, and then use Qt Creator refactor tools to automatically add a definition in the .cpp file, I'll get `const` placed in the wrong place, and the `&` will be next to the variable, which I also don't like:

```
double f(const double &x) { return x + x; }
```

How can I modify this default behavior in Qt Creator?

Comment: Easy and simple: You can't.

Comment: Get to Qt Creator's Options or Preferences, then: `C++ -> Code Style -> <Select a code style> -> Edit... -> Pointers and References`. Edit as you please. Also note that this may be overriden on a per-project basis; Look also at the per-project settings, there's a roughly analogous panel. Per-project settings will override the global setting.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist +1 Thanks. I can bind `*` and `&` to the type instead of the identifier. However, I do not see an option to change the `const` placement?

Comment: @becko That's the part I don't know how to do unfortunately. But `C++ -> Code Style` is the place to dig in, if it's at all possible.